# Command to find default program related to file(.pdf) using command line in windows OS

Tags: java, windows, swing, cmd, registry

Is there any command through which I can find that user has selected a particular program (e.g. Adobe reader/Adobe acrobat) as default program for a particular file extension (e.g. .pdf) in Windows?

More specifically:

- If I select `adobe reader` as default `PDF viewer` from file properties
- String `viewer1 = "Command .pdf"` (running in command prompt)
- Then I change to acrobat from file properties → change default program
- String `viewer2 = "Command .pdf"` (running in command prompt)

So,  viewer1 != viewer2

I am working in Java swing, so if there is any library or way to find default program selected to .pdf file, that would also helpful for me.

Does any registry key exist, that stores default program path for specific file extension (.pdf)?

Comment: What do you try to achieve ? If you just want to open a PDF file with the default application, you can use the `Desktop#open` method

Comment: Buddy, I have used this `Desktop.getDesktop().open(docFile)` code but after installing **Foxit Reader** it works unevenly.Thats why written a question here.To find operating level solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Okay so I missed a part here. It consists of two commands.

1. `assoc` to get the filetype association with the extension e.g. `.jpg=jpegimage`
2. `ftype` to get the default handler `ftype jpegimage`

Hope that helps. I suppose you could pipeline the two but I have no idea how thats done in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer but it returns AcroExch.document for both the case(Befor and after changing default program for .pdf file).

Comment: Its the best I can think of. I dont think there is any built in cmd function for this unless its part of powershell.

Comment: I dont know if some experts have some way!! I am serching for it from many days

Comment: i think i have an answer just hold on

Comment: Ya buddy it gets worked and it shows the path of that program, but i found a new issue after installing "foxit reader" "assoc .pdf" only returns "FoxitReader.Document". So i think i have to go with java libraries only...Thanks for your assistance buddy :)

Comment: @JaykishanMehta You can then type `reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FoxitReader.Document\shell\open\command`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet : OP needs a way to make it work for whichever software the user has set to default.

Comment: @HanutSingh The `reg query` actually returns the same info as `ftype`.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet : Not really ftype returns the default file opener associated with the file type while reg query will search the registry for a particular entry. `Returns a list of the next tier of subkeys and entries that are located under a specified subkey in the registry.` [source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: @Hanut The query Is specified will return the same as ftype. Anyway, it does not matter.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet : true enough. It's just that using reg query you would have to know the program before hand.

Answer (score 1):

The default command associated with a given extension can be determined like this:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('assoc .pdf') do ftype %a
```

Change `%a` to `%%a` if you want to use this in a batch file.

A manual override of the associated command via the file's properties, however, seems to be stored elsewhere (in the `Progid` value of the key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\UserChoice` to be specific), so it won't be detected by `assoc`. You can read it from the registry like this:

```
reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\UserChoice /v Progid
```

Comment: I was having Adobe reader in my PC.Then I have installed Adobe Acrobat.Now I am changing my preference to open `.pdf` file in Adobe Reader.Now I am Using your command, but it showing me path of acrobat though it should return Adobe Reader's path. :(